# How do I prioritise different agents type in the same queue to different vehicles?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

So I have three different agent types: PatientType1, PatientType2 and PatientType3. These three agent type are all connected to one QueueBlock, so that they all become an agent. Furthermore, this queue block is connected to a selectoutput5 block which is again further connected to three different vehicles: Ambulance, vans and busses. So basically, the goal here is to prioritize so that all of the patienttype1 get transported with ambulance to a location and when that is done the ambulance can also carry patienttype2 and patienttype3. In the mean time, the busses and vans should prioritise patienttype2 and carry these, and when there are none patienttype2 left, patienttype 3 can be transported. So to summarize:

Ambulance transportation for all type1 until there are no type1 left, then go for type2 or type3. In the mean time, busses and van should carry type2 until there are noe type2 left, then go for type3.

Here is the flow:

- PatientType1       ---------------------------------------------------------->                                        Ambulance (Pick-up Block)
- PatientType2 ->  Queue -> SelectOutput5(Only using three) -> Vans (Pick-up Block)
- PatientType3    ------------------------------------------------------------> Busses (Pick-up Block)

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Can you clarify: do ambulances, vans and busses have different capacity? Also, do they pick up whoever is waiting at the time or wait to be filled?

Answer (score 0):

This will not work with a single queue, I think. Even prioritizing by "agent comparison" using code such as `agent1 instanceof PatientType1 ? ...` would not help you with those secondary capabilities.

You could use a `Wait` block instead. It does not prioritize but lumps all patients together.

Then, your vehicles actively seek out patients by type. You loop through all patients in the Wait block and "pull" those that respect your rule (so ambulance first pulls all type1, then type2...).

However, since you need to sort all patients everytime by their type, this might be slow.

Even better would be to put them into a collection of type `PriorityQueue` that is automatically sorted by your patient types. But this would be a bit more advanced Java...

Otherwise, simply use 3 queues (1 for each patient type) with your current setup.